# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters при отправке письма

Tags: python, email, gmail

Всем добрый день. Возник вопрос при написании программы. Пытаюсь запустить скрипт, но возникает ошибка

Вот код:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

fromaddr = "pochhhta@gmail.com"
toaddr = "andr3y1993@mail.ru"
mypass = "пароль от pochhhta@gmail.com"

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "Привет от питона"

body = "Это пробное сообщение"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, mypass)
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/iljal/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    server.login(fromaddr, mypass)
  File "C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 723, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 634, in auth
    response = encode_base64(initial_response.encode('ascii'), eol='')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 20-25: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как устранить проблему? Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Возможно пароль состоит из русский символов

Comment: такой пароль я поставил для примера, на самом деле он на англ буквах и с символами (обычный пароль от почты)

Comment: Не нужно один и тот же вопрос задавать несколько раз.

Comment: Может в toaddr кирилица,указывает на server.login(fromaddr, mypass).body также кирилица,весь файл не в юникоде или библиотека не принимает кирилицу,или имя компа-локалхоста в кирилице,что то такое у меня было во Flask.

Comment: text = msg.as_string() скорее всего дело в https://stackoverflow.com/a/9942885/12785139

Comment: Спасибо! Могли бы пожалуйста помочь с этим вопросом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1124887/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-twitter-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python

Answer (score -1):

Уберите всюду кирилические символы и всё заработает. Кодировка вашего файла скорее всего не utf-8.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/513281)

Comment: Вы можете предложить лучшее решение? И какое же?